# WIX Blog REST API draftPost with Rich Content fails

Tags: rest, velo

Trying to create a blog draft post using the WIX REST API. The issue is richContent. If I remove it from the params by adding the line `params.draftPost.richContent = {};`
the draft post is created properly. If I include it, the draft post fails with a 500 error message: 'str.substring is not a function'. This same payload works in their API tester located here https://dev.wix.com/api/rest/wix-blog/blog/draft-posts/create-draft-post

```
//
// Create a new blog draft
//
const axios = require('axios')
const mySecret =      "obfuscated"
const account_id =    "3ce23514-62b3-4167-a04a-ad0b131b09e9";
const my_site_id =    "ab60bafa-00c1-409e-9225-4b1e53bc831e";
const  headers = {
    "Content-Type":   "application/json",
    "Authorization":  mySecret,
    'wix-account-id': account_id,
    'wix-site-id':    my_site_id
    }

const params = { "draftPost": {
    "title": "abc1",
    "memberId":"3ce23514-62b3-4167-a04a-ad0b131b09e9",   
    "richContent": {
        "nodes": [ 
        { 
            "type": "PARAGRAPH",
            "id": "foo",
            "nodes": [            {
              "type": "TEXT",
              "id": "foo2",
              "nodes": [],
              "textData":               {
                "text": "This is a paragraph of text.",
                "decorations": []
              }
            }],
            "paragraphData": {
              "textStyle": {"textAlignment": "AUTO"},
              "indentation": 0
            }
          } 
         ]
      }
    }
  ,"publish":false
  ,"fieldSets":["RICH_CONTENT"]
}

const options = {
  url: '/draft-posts',
  method: 'post', 
  baseURL: 'https://www.wixapis.com/blog/v3',
  headers: headers,
  params: params,
  timeout: 2000
}

axios(options)
  .then(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the payload as options.data not as options.params